# springboot LaunchedURLClassLoader throws error class exceeds the maximum class size supported by the JVM (constant pool too big)

Tags: spring-boot, rest, aspectj

I have a legacy application and one of the java file have lines around 280000. I have a spring boot application for restful services and one of the service calls this huge JAVA file. The application works fine when I load the application without aspectjweaver but fails when I specify javaagent in java options. I have tried JVM heap but it doesn't help.

Following is the error stacktrace:

```
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@7cbd213e] error at MYCLASS.java::0 The class MYCLASS exceeds the maximum class size supported by the JVM (constant pool too big).
Aug 14, 2020 3:42:01 PM org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace error
SEVERE: MYCLASS 
java.lang.RuntimeException: key not found in wovenClassFile
        at org.aspectj.weaver.WeaverStateInfo.findEndOfKey(WeaverStateInfo.java:408)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.WeaverStateInfo.replaceKeyWithDiff(WeaverStateInfo.java:364)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.getJavaClassBytesIncludingReweavable(LazyClassGen.java:711)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.getClassFilesFor(BcelWeaver.java:1448)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1410)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1188)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:527)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:363)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:121)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:54)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getConstructors(ClassUtil.java:1162)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedCreatorCollector._findPotentialConstructors(AnnotatedCreatorCollector.java:101)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedCreatorCollector.collect(AnnotatedCreatorCollector.java:56)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspectJ transforms the original byte code, adding additional instructions and data to it. So your monster class - who would write such a crazy big class anyway without being ashamed of calling himself a programmer? - simply gets too big because probably it was near the JVM per-class size limit to begin with.

What can you do? Well, that depends on the situation:

- Refactor the class into smaller pieces, covering the refactoring with automated tests making sure the broken-down thing does the same afterwards as before. Legacy or not, code is code and you can modify it.
- If for whatever reason you are too scared, unskilled or lazy to refactor and lucky enough that the monster class actually does not need to be advised by any aspects, you can just modify your pointcuts to be less global and more specific, excluding the monster class or maybe even a bigger chunk of the legacy package, depending on your use case.